# How to dictate a unit test response from a function in JS

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, parse-platform

I have a function here I'm writing a test for that calls another function on an external server (parse.com). Its my first time doing this type of thing.

How do I write a test so that second function function returns a specific value?

```js
$scope.signInClick = function() {
      console.log('Login was clicked');
      console.log('$scope.user.username: ' + $scope.user.username);
      console.log('$scope.user.password: ' + $scope.user.password);
       
        $scope.loading = $ionicLoading.show({
            content: 'Logging in',
            animation: 'fade-in',
            showBackdrop: true,
            maxWidth: 200,
            showDelay: 0
        });

        Parse.User.logIn(($scope.user.username) , $scope.user.password, {
            success: function(_user) {
                console.log('Login Success');
                console.log('user = ' + _user.attributes.username);
                console.log('email = ' + _user.attributes.email);
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                $rootScope.user = _user;
                $rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
                $state.go('tab.home');
            },
            error: function(user, err) {
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                if (err.code === 101) {2
                    $scope.error.message = 'Invalid login credentials';
                } else {
                    $scope.error.message = 'An unexpected error has ' +
                        'occurred, please try again.';
                }
                console.log('error message on Parse.User.logIn: ' + $scope.error.message);
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });
      $state.go('tab.home');
  };
```

I have to dictate that Parse.User.logIn returns an error, or a success, or an error of a particular type, so forth..

How do I mock that?

EDIT:

So, still been working on this, and I figured out one way to 'do' it, which was create a spy object just for the Parse.User.logIn (which is really the only thing being called).

But out of curiosity, why doesn't it work when I do that, but call `$scope.signInClick` ? Is there a way to get that function to call my spied on Parse object? When I try to call `$scope.signInClick`, I get that Parse is undefined.

Another thing: Is doing it this way missing the point of testing? Is this just dictating some code to do something, when we should be paying attention to the code that's actually in the app instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dependency injection or monkey patching to replace the real Parse functions with your own.

```
var Parse = {
  Unit: {
    logIn: function(userName, pass, callbackObj) {
      callbacObj.success({
        attributes: {
          username: "testuser",
          email: "testuser@example.com"
        }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The above is an example of the positive case but you could change it around to always call the error function instead.

Comment: Neat, so I would just put something like that that in the beforeEach block, and then it would just refer to that object when the line `Parse.User.logIn` comes along?

Comment: Hmm, I did that - did `var Parse`, then in `beforeEach()` put `Parse = {all that stuff}`, and I got the same error `referenceError: Parse is not defined`. Any more direction about this would be appreciated! Reading the docs.

Answer (score 0):

There is no indication as to where Parse comes into the piece of code you've provided but basically what you should do is create a simplified mocked object that will act as the service, providing you with the results you'd normally expect from the real server.

Comment: it comes in with Parse.User.logIn. That's parse code that calls to the parse server.